# sending inform notification to local SNMP server

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I am sending SNMP inform notification by Pysnmp. When I sent my custom data to a foreign IP:

```
config.addTargetAddr(
    snmpEngine, 'my-nms',
    udp.domainName, ('104.236.166.95', 162),
    'my-creds',
    tagList='all-my-managers'
)
```

I deliver response from server but on my local IP

```
config.addTargetAddr(
    snmpEngine, 'my-nms',
    udp.domainName, ('127.0.0.1', 162),
    'my-creds',
    tagList='all-my-managers'
)
```

i deliver timeout error. i had run snmpd service on my UBUNTU. and configure it for all agent.

Comment: Is it that you are sending your query to one address (104.236.166.95) but receiving response on the address you do not expect to? In that case you may want to explicitly bind your client to the address to which you want your server to deliver response (e.g. *udp.domainName, ('104.236.166.95', 162').setLocalAddress(('0.0.0.0', 0))*). If this is not your question, you might need to explain your problem in more details or code. ;-)

Comment: i mean  that my local SNMP server dosnt respond to my inform query.  maybe i need have more configuration but i dont know more about it. i just have some data that i want send it on my local server but the followingerror has occured : Notification 1366832429 scheduled to be sent
Notification 1366832430, status - No SNMP response received before timeout

Comment: It looks like your local server is not getting your request or it is not answering to it or its response does not reach your client script. So you need to make sure that your local snmpd is configured properly and responds to INFORM PDUs. You may first debug that with the `snmpinform` tool to rule out pysnmp problems.

Comment: thank you. may you help me to configure my snmpd  configuration

Comment: please spend 1 minute learning [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) with markdown which is used by most modern websites including SO. No one will read that mess in your post. And please write in proper casing

Answer (score 0):

i find that i must make a snmptrapd.conf and define an authocommuntity public then start snmptrapd service and now i can send trap and inform request to net-snmp.